# Choose which one of 2 ambiguous fields to output in mysql case select

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `tracks`, which looks like this:

```
persistent_id       artist  name    play_count
C660FF302599636B    artist1 name1   14
0BDDB14AE2CC4675    artist2 name2   78
000ABA9AB1DCD725    artist3 name3   10
00361E574E776781    artist4 name4   10
```

I'm making a select where I want to sum the `play_count` of `C660FF302599636B` and `0BDDB14AE2CC4675`, but otherwise display the other info like `artist` and `name` of `C660FF302599636B`, this way:

```
SELECT artist, name, sum(play_count), 
    case when tracks.Persistent_ID IN ('C660FF302599636B', '0BDDB14AE2CC4675')
        THEN 'C660FF302599636B'
        ELSE tracks.Persistent_ID 
    END Persistent_ID
FROM tracks
GROUP BY case when tracks.Persistent_ID IN ('C660FF302599636B', '0BDDB14AE2CC4675')
            THEN 'C660FF302599636B'
            ELSE tracks.Persistent_ID 
        END
ORDER BY sum(play_count) DESC
```

Which gets me this result:

```
artist2 name2   92  C660FF302599636B
artist3 name3   10  000ABA9AB1DCD725
artist4 name4   10  00361E574E776781
```

Whereas I want this result:

```
artist1 name1   92  C660FF302599636B
artist3 name3   10  000ABA9AB1DCD725
artist4 name4   10  00361E574E776781
```

I know both `name`s and `artist`s get selected, because if I do a `group_concat` I see it (`substring_index(group_concat(artist), ',', -1)`), but whether it is the first or second substring seems random for each row.

Comment: `name` is not uniquely determined by the grouping expression. Both `name1` and `name2` are in the `C660FF302599636B` group, why should it prefer to return `name1` rather than `name2`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a self-join to choose the value of `artist` and `name` to return.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(IF(t1.Persistent_ID = 'C660FF302599636B', t1.artist, t2.artist)) AS artist, 
    MAX(IF(t1.Persistent_ID = 'C660FF302599636B', t1.name, t2.name)) AS name, 
    sum(t1.play_count) AS total_play_count, 
    case when t1.Persistent_ID IN ('C660FF302599636B', '0BDDB14AE2CC4675')
        THEN 'C660FF302599636B'
        ELSE t1.Persistent_ID 
    END Persistent_ID
FROM tracks AS t1
JOIN tracks AS t2 ON t1.Persistent_ID = t2.Persistent_ID
GROUP BY Persistent_ID
ORDER BY total_play_count DESC
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g4mCr1xFuVoWbSJ5bySHYD/0)

I'm assuming `Persistent_ID` is a unique column in the table, so the join is 1-to-1, not a cross product.

BTW, there's no need to repeat the `CASE` expression in `GROUP BY`. Since you assigned an alias to the same expression in the `SELECT` list, you can refer to that alias.